# How to change sliding direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slide, sidebar

I work at an sidebar (left & right) which I can slide out/in with jQuery.
Both sides works but the right sidebar slides in left direction instead to right.
I use the following jQuery-code:

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
    var left_open = true;
    var right_open = true;
    $('a#ToogleSidebarLeft').click(function () {
        if (left_open === true) {
            $('#boxwrapper-left').animate({ width: 'hide' });
            $('#leftcolumn').animate({ width: 'hide' });
            $("#maincontent").animate({ marginLeft: "0px" });
            left_open = false;
        } else {
            $('#boxwrapper-left').animate({ width: 'show' });
            $('#leftcolumn').animate({ width: 'show' });
            $("#maincontent").animate({ marginLeft: "220px" });
            left_open = true;
        }
    });
    $('a#ToogleSidebarRight').click(function () {
        if (right_open === true) {
            $('#boxwrapper-right').animate({ width: 'hide' });
            $('#rightcolumn').animate({ width: 'hide' });
            // $('#boxwrapper-right').hide('slide', {width: 'hide', direction: 'right' });
            // $('#rightcolumn').hide('slide', { width: 'hide', direction: 'right' });
            $("#maincontent").animate({ marginRight: "0px" });
            right_open = false;
        } else {
            $('#boxwrapper-right').animate({ width: 'show' });
            $('#rightcolumn').animate({ width: 'show' });
            $("#maincontent").animate({ marginRight: "200px" });
            right_open = true;
        }
    });
});
```

How can I change the sliding-direction of the second function (ToogleSidebarRight) to right?

I have try  something like this but it doesn't works so:

```
$('#boxwrapper-left').animate({ width: 'hide', direction: 'right' });
```

Thanks for helping!

PS: English isn't my native language, so the text looks maybe a little bit strange...

Comment: not 'native language' - 'mother tongue' :)

Comment: that is, what I meant with "strange" :D, thanks

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair Nach Leo.org beduetet "native language" aber auch "Muttersprache" oder braucht man dies in einem anderen Zusammenhang? Gruss aus der Schweiz ;-)

Comment: hab' bis dato von muttersprachlern immer nur "mother tongue" gehört/gelesen ... im unterricht heißt's zwar native speaker ... vmtl. hasste recht :) gruß aus österreich!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#maincontent").animate({ marginRight: "-200px" });
```

I think negative value of margin will work.

or change it to

```
$("#maincontent").animate({ marginLeft: "200px" });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's not the maincontent. It is the div "boxwrapper-right". The animation works but goes to the wrong direction (left instead right)

Answer (score 0):

[there](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions) are plenty of examples available ... i hope you can extract the needed piece...

> Finally, we can achieve the same
>   effect as the left animation by
>   animating the marginLeft property. In
>   this case, we still need overflow:
>   hidden; on the parent element, but the
>   sliding element does not need to be
>   positioned.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slidemarginleft button').click(function() {
        var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
        $marginLefty.animate({
            marginLeft: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginLeft'),10) == 0 ? $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
        });
    });
});
```